# Expectation of two dependent normal distribution

Tags: probability

$U,V,W$ are independent normal distributions with $0$ mean and unit variance. I am given $X=U+W, Y=U+V$.How can I find $E[XY]$?

I know $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, But clarely, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent from each other, so I can't apply E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]. And I don't have $Cov(XY)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $$XY = (U+W)(U+V) = U^2 + UV + UW + VW.$$  And if $U$, $V$ are independent, then $\operatorname{E}[UV] = \operatorname{E}[U]\operatorname{E}[V]$, for example.

Comment: silly me, never think of developing the expression. Thanks a lot.